# IOS- UITableView scroll back to top

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview, cell

i am using Custom `UITableView` in my project for displaying data it works fine but when i try to scroll it to bottom it doesn't stop at desired cell it always jumps to the top of the table. only shows 2-3 cells.
please suggest what to add to overcome this problem.

i tried so many codes answered in similar type of questions but they doesn't work

i uses the following codes for `UITableView`

```
newsFeedTable = [[UITableView alloc]init];
    CGFloat Ytablepadding = CGRectGetMaxY(homeView.frame)+60;
    CGFloat heighttable = 700;
    newsFeedTable.frame = CGRectMake(0,Ytablepadding, self.view.frame.size.width, heighttable);
    [self.view addSubview:newsFeedTable];
    newsFeedTable.delegate=self;
    newsFeedTable.dataSource= self;
```

Comment: " i try to scroll it to bottom it doesn't stop at desired cell" >> you are scrolling to bottom programmatically or manually

Comment: through programmatically

Comment: can you share your code where you are scrolling programmatically

Comment: tableview is automatically scrolled to bottom and shows all cells but in my case its not scrolling it jumps to the top always i tried to scroll so my question is how to overcome this issue

Comment: so you are not able to see some of the bottom  cell even if you scroll  down

Comment: yes when i scroll the tableview it jumps to the top automatically

Comment: i thnk you have solved your problem from @ayush answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this code in you viewDidload :

```
NSIndexPath *myIndexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:AddYourLastIndex inSection:0];
[self.tbl_presentation selectRowAtIndexPath:myIndexPath animated:YES scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionBottom];
```

Answer (score 1):

UITableView is a subclass of UIScrollView, so you can also use:

[newsFeedTable scrollRectToVisible:CGRectMake(0, 0, 1, 1) animated:YES];
Or

[newsFeedTable setContentOffset:CGPointZero animated:YES];

Answer (score 0):

You need to adjust the table view's height according to the height of the view, of which you are making subview to see the last row of the table or rather to scroll it to bottom:

```
newsFeedTable.frame = CGRectMake(0,Ytablepadding, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height - Ytablepadding);
```

and to scroll it to last row on table reload/ after popping of data, scroll it programatically like this:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
                [newsFeedTable reloadData];

                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                    int lastRowNumber = [newsFeedTable numberOfRowsInSection:0] - 1; 
                    NSIndexPath* ip = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:lastRowNumber inSection:0];
                    [newsFeedTable scrollToRowAtIndexPath:ip atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop animated:NO];
                });

            });

        }];
```

Answer (score 0):

Simplest you can do is :
calling `[newsFeedTable setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, CGFLOAT_MAX)]`
 will do what you want.